# Cache has been closed exception

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I am getting "*Cache has been closed*" exception when accessing Ignite Cache for querying. What I'm doing is simply,

```
CacheConfiguration cfg = new CacheConfiguration();
cacheConfiguration.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
cacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT);        cacheConfiguration.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.PRIMARY_SYNC);
IgniteCache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);
```

After initializing this, in other place in my code I am calling `cache.get("key")`; But it's throwing exception.

Cache variable is member of some class's object. Why can't the cache be kept open till it is closed manually.

I AM NOT CLOSING IT ANYWHERE

Answer (score 1):

Usually it happens when client is disconnected, servers go down, or client rejoins with new ID since you're not calling `.close()` or .`destory()` anywhere in your code.